# Using GitLab Omnibus behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, gitlab

I installed the omnibus package in my Debian server. The thing is, I actually have Nginx installed, used to serve some other services.

How can I redirect, e.g. myserver.com/gitlab to the Gitlab's own Nginx?

I don't know if there's another way to do it, but I'm really, really lost with this issue since I'm totally new to Gitlab and Nginx (and web servers-services in general).

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=gitlab%20nginx

Comment: You are using the wrong concept. You should disable the nginx of gitlab and create your own configuration. Check `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, there you will find all information how to use your own nginx server. It is recommended to copy the gitlab nginx config in `/var/lib/gitlab/...` so you know which sockets are important. If you run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` after changing your configuration, gitlab will set read/write permissions for the given nginx user.